# Upload Function with Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, jqwidget

I've been trying to use jqxUploadFiles but instead of php I need to use python.

In a code like below;

```
from flask import request
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, ALL

def upload_file():

    files = UploadSet('files', ALL)
    app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = '/uploads'
    configure_uploads(app, files)
    filename = files.save(request.files['files'])
    return filename
```

where `app = Flask(__name__)`

but in this project there is;

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__)
```

where it used like `@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

and there is a create_app function;

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config['development'])

    with app.app_context():
        db.app = app
        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all()
```

and it is used in manage.py file;

```
app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db)
manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))


@manager.command
def test():
    """Run the unit tests."""
    import unittest
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

So I need to use a function like "upload_file()" but I couldn't understand how "app" created by "create_app()" and Blueprint() relates to each other and how can I use it in upload_file().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you had better make a file defined `app`, and use it from other script file.

Using this `app`, you can register `Blueprint` object.

The example below is actually a script that worked.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_script import Server, Manager, Shell
from view import top
from app import app

app.register_blueprint(top.main)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.33.40') # please change host
```

`view/top.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint("top", __name__, url_prefix="/")

from flask import request, render_template, redirect
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, ALL

from app import app

def upload_file():

    files = UploadSet('files', ALL)
    app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = '/tmp' # please change
    configure_uploads(app, files)
    filename = files.save(request.files['files'])
    return filename

@main.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('top/index.html')

@main.route('upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    upload_file()
    return redirect('/')
```

`templates/top/index.html`

```
<form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="/upload">
    <input type=file name=files>
    <input type=submit value=upload>
</form>
```

If you have any questions please ask anything!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems like there is a thing that i have to check inside the widget, a similar code works with a simple html but with widget i keep getting bad request error.